# Date format change in php

Tags: php

I've the date format 12/May/2018. I need to change it to 2018-12-05.Please help me.

```
$originalDate = "12/May/2018";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate;
```

Output: 1969-12-31

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? `Y-m-d` would result in `2018-05-12`, not `2018-12-05`.

Comment: Some response would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code :

```
$originalDate = "12/May/2018";
$originalDate =str_replace("/", " ", $originalDate);
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for any manual parsing.
You should use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, which is much more flexible than the old `date()`-function.

Here's an example that does what you want:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', '12/May/2018');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Y5HF0

Answer (score 0):

That date format is not supported by strtotime.
But replacing the `/` with space is a supported format.

```
$originalDate = "12/May/2018";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/", " " ,$originalDate)));
echo $newDate;
```

https://3v4l.org/K8cOF

The reason you get 1969-12-31 is because UNIX 0 is 1970-01-01 00:00:00.
When strtotime can't parse the date it returns `false`.
False can be typeconverted to `0`.
That means date reads it as "Y-m-d" at UNIX time 0 (1970), and because of your timezone you get 1969-12-31.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$originalDate = "12/May/2018";
$newDate = date_format(date_create_from_format("j/F/Y", $originalDate), 'Y-m-d');
echo $newDate;
```

Note : if your day format is `01` use `d`, if `1` use `j`

The output is: 2018-05-12